# what is the laravel command to deploy the enter database without seed?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hi i would like to command to deploy the entire database without seed. and I have some other questions as well related to laravel. I want to convert following sql query to laravel eloquent format.

```
select * from user where id = '123' and password = 'abcd';
select name, address from user where lower('name') like lower('%Jerry%');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean to create database structure without data then it is

```
php artisan migrate
```

For your second question your queries would be:

```
User::where(‘id’, 123)->where(‘password’, ‘abcd’)->first();
User::whereRaw(‘lower(name) like lower(“%Jerry%”))->first();
```

You need to have user model for that. I recommend to read eloquent documentation to have a proper understanding.